# NUnit 2.5.9 and WebAii

Tags: silverlight, nunit, webaii, nunit-2.5.9

I'm attempting to write my own NUnit tests for a Silverlight application using WebAii. I've been attempting to follow a rather detailed blog over at http://borntocode.co.uk/page/Setting-Up-a-WebAii-Test-Project-with-NUnit.aspx however I simply can't find NUnit.Core.TestContext.Out.WriteLine

The blog is using version 2.5.7 however I'm using 2.5.9 and can't find this. I wouldn't have expected such a major section of NUnit (allowing direction of error messages) to have moved so drastically. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

TestExecutionContext is the equivalent of TestContext in 2.6

Answer (score 0):

The TestContext appears to exist under NUnit.Framework instead of NUnit.Core.  I'm not sure if it still has the properties you are expecting

Comment: I found that too, annoyingly it seems to have completely different properties and doesn't help.